# Weblogic cluster 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am working in Spring -MVC project which is deployed in Weblogic server, it was configured with 2 clusters. We are getting `"401 (Unauthorized)"` error when request is hit from one cluster to another cluster.

But it works for some request and causing this error sometime.

Any idea why is this happening ?

Answer (score 1):

If you delegate security to the Servlet Container and deploy your App to 2 different clusters (ClusterA, ClusterB) you will have by default two different sessions SessionA and SessionB (  with the same cookie name, JSESSIONID ). If you don't have session Affinity and yoour request jumps from ClusterA to ClusterB your SessionA (with a Subject) will not be valid on ClusterB.

If you're looking for Maximum Availability  by a two clusters Topology consider delegating HTTP Session State to Coherence (see Coherence*Web at http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHCW/cweb_wls.htm#CHDDGJHJ).

With this topology you can share your session between many apps deployed on different clusters (or even different WebLogic Server domains and/or different Application Servers).

Comment: But for some request it is success and for some request it ended with this error.

Comment: Do you have in memory replication enabled? <persistent-store-type/> element in weblogic.xml descriptor:

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in memory replication enabled(disabled by default)? ( element in weblogic.xml descriptor. If no, enable it with:

```
 <session-descriptor>
    <persistent-store-type>replicated_if_clustered</persistent-store-type>
 </session-descriptor>
```

When the first request comes to any Managed Server in ClusterA it creates a SessionID (check your JSESSIONID cookie in your browser).

How do you balance your request between both clusters(Hardware Load Balancer or Web Server + Proxy Plug-In)

How do you maintain cluster affinity?

If there is no cluster affinity, all the request processed by any Managed Server in ClusterA have access to session state (replicated internally by the WLS Cluster when In Memory replication is enabled), but if cluster affinity fails and the request (originally serverd by ClusterA) is processed by any Managed Server in Cluster B, the Servlet Container will not find any  HTTSession identified by your cookie with ClusterB and it will fail and create a new Session (check the cookie in your browser).